# MySQL - Select Users with certain privileges (INNER JOIN)

Tags: php, mysql, select, inner-join

Hello I need to select all users with privileges, 1, 2 and 3 from a table named "USERS".
After that, I will use their ID to do a new select at another table, named "Status".

```
<?php
include_once("include/connection.php");
$sql = 'select * from USERS where Privileges != "4"';

$rs = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die ("error");
$op = mysqli_num_rows($rs);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
{
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $name = $row['Name'];
    $priv = $row['Privileges'];

    $sql = 'select * from Status where ID="$id"';
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die ("database error");
    $gmon = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $login = $row['Login'];

    switch($login)
    {
        case "ONLINE":
            $login = "<font color=\"#84FB84\"><strong>".$name."</strong></font>";
            break;
        case "OFFLINE":
            $login = "<font color=\"#46AAEB\"><strong>".$name."</strong></font>";
            break;
    }
    $online_adms .= "<td>$login</td>";
}
?>
<?php echo $online_adms; ?>
```

**UPDATE** 
I can't get the output for "$login" variable...
If I try to output "$name" or "$id", it works fine...but I need to output the "$login".
I guess I can use some INNER JOin here...

Any clues?

Thanks.

**SOLUTION**

```
$sql = 'SELECT c.Name, c.ID, c.Privileges, d.Login FROM USERS c 
        INNER JOIN Status d 
        ON c.ID = d.ID
        where Privileges != 4';
```

Comment: Isn't working? Can you reduce the scope of that description a bit?

Comment: What is the error, why isn't the code working?

Comment: "RedFilter" and "rationalboss" - I depend on 2 tables: Users and Status (respectively). "Users" table, will return me all users under the searched privileges. After filter only desired users, I'll search only online users between them.

Comment: I don't see where you use the value stored in $result (containing select * from status). Did you mean to?

Answer (score 1):

you could select all the required fields with a join

```
SELECT `ID`,`Name`,`Privileges`,`Login` 
 FROM `USERS` 
 INNER JOIN `Status`
 ON `USERS`.`ID` = `Status`.`ID`
 WHERE Privileges != 4
```

then remove your second query

Answer (score 0):

If you are just getting PHP syntax errors, you forgot to close the while loop. Here is the corrected code:

```
$sql = 'select * from USERS where Privileges != "4"';

$rs = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die ("error");
$op = mysqli_num_rows($rs);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
{
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $name = $row['Name'];
    $priv = $row['Privileges'];

    $sql = 'select * from Status where ID="$id"';
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die ("database error");
    $gmon = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $login = $row['Login'];

    switch($login)
    {
        case "ONLINE":
            $login = "<font color=\"#84FB84\"><strong>".$name."</strong></font>";
            break;
        case "OFFLINE":
            $login = "<font color=\"#46AAEB\"><strong>".$name."</strong></font>";
            break;
        default:
            $login = 'OOPS! The value of $login is '.$login.' that is why nothing is being printed. :(';
    }
}
```

Also, you might want to improve your line:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die ("database error");
```

by:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die ("database error: ".mysql_error().'<br />query: '.$sql);
```

Comment: okay, what is the error you are getting? $connect is null in your full code.

Comment: okay, this is very important: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: There is no error.
I can output $name, $id...I just can't output the $login.

Comment: i updated the code. it's probably because $row['Login'] contains another value other than ONLINE and OFFLINE

Comment: While not strictly needed in this case, might want to top off that default: with a break;

Comment: rational...that didn't worked. Anyway, I managed to do a INNER JOIN which fixed the issue, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it appears that the Login column is supposed to be in the Status table, but it wasn't being used. Try something like this:

```
<?php
include_once("include/connection.php");
$sql  = 'SELECT USERS.*, STATUS.* FROM USERS INNER JOIN STATUS ';
$sql .= 'ON USERS.ID=STATUS.ID WHERE USERS.Privileges != "4"';

$rs = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die ("error");
$op = mysqli_num_rows($rs);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
{
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $name = $row['Name'];
    $priv = $row['Privileges'];
    $login = "<font color=\"#46AAEB\"><strong>".$name."</strong></font>";
    $loginStatus = $row['Login'];

    switch($loginStatus)
    {
        case "ONLINE":
            $login = "<font color=\"#84FB84\"><strong>".$name."</strong></font>";
            break;
        case "OFFLINE":
            $login = "<font color=\"#46AAEB\"><strong>".$name."</strong></font>";
            break;
        default:
            $login = "<font color=\"#999999\"><strong>".$name."</strong></font>";
            break;
    }
    $online_adms .= "<td>$login</td>";
}
?>
<?php echo $online_adms; ?>
```

Comment: It does displays the users now...but not dinamically. It should display which is online with GREEN color and RED which is offline.

Comment: Ok; out of curiousity, what is the SQL column type of "Login"? I'm assuming in this case that it is either an enum or a String.

Comment: Alright, and the two possible values are "ONLINE" and "OFFLINE", and not "online" and "offline"? Also, I did update my query to just use an INNER JOIN

Comment: Also added a default login status (shows gray if neither ONLINE nor OFFLINE)